# How can I create a multi row radiobutton using a for loop

Tags: tkinter, menu, radio-button

I'm trying to create a multi row radiobutton for a character selection menu

I created a for loop based radio button indexing the list of characters and their images. When run though, it creates a singular line that trails off  outside the window. I could add a scrollbar and leave it as is, but it would look and be better if I could have multiple rows instead.

I've tried creating a second row manually and using the grid method, but it only references the last entry in the index when i do that. I have also setup multiple frames instead to do this, but there will still be more options than the window can hold. So I would need to still end up scrolling up and down as well, but with the multiple frames method, I don't believe thats possible.

Current state of the code:

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x640")
window.resizable(False, False)
```

```
topframe = Frame(window)
topframe.pack(side = TOP)
frame2 = Frame(window)
frame2.pack(side = TOP)
bottomframe = Frame(window)
bottomframe.pack(side= TOP)
#Button!
button = Button(topframe,
                image=unselected,
                command=start_on
                )
button.pack(anchor = N, side = TOP)
```

```
for index in range(len(characters)):
 
    rb1 = Radiobutton(frame2,
    compound = TOP,
    image = characterList[index],
    text=characters[index],
    variable=v,
    value=index,
    ).pack(
            side = LEFT, 
            pady = 20,
            padx = 13,
            )

for index in range(7, len(characters)):
 
    rb2 = Radiobutton(bottomframe,
    compound = TOP,
    image = characterList[index],
    text=characters[index],
    variable=v,
    value=index,
    ).pack(
            side = LEFT, 
            pady = 5,
            padx = 13,
            )

for index in range(7, len(characters)):
 
    rb3 = Radiobutton(bottomframe,
    compound = TOP,
    image = characterList[index],
    text=characters[index],
    variable=v,
    value=index,
    ).pack(
            side = LEFT, 
            pady = 5,
            padx = 13,
            )
```

Using grid:

```
for index in range(len(characters)):
 
    rb1 = Radiobutton(frame2,
    compound = TOP,
    image = characterList[index],
    text=characters[index],
    variable=v,
    value=index,
    # ).pack(
    #         side = LEFT, 
    #         padx = 13,
    #         )
        ).grid(
            # row = 1, #Shows Only the last entry in the characters index.
            column = 1, #Shows characters in a row only. And does not change position of the row(stays center no matter the int.)
            # rowspan = 3, # Same as using column = 1
            # columnspan = 5, #Same as using column = 1
            #using any combination of column/rowspan/columnspan shows the same as using any of those 3 by itself.
            # adding row = int to any combination of the above does the same as if its all thats being used.
            )
```

Comment: I don't understand why using `grid()` doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but as stated, it pulls only the last entry in the index. even when using columnspan/rowspan

Comment: It is better to post the code on using `grid()`.

Comment: I posted what I'm using for grid() and an explanation of what i'm seeing when I use any of the grid options.

Comment: Why do you use same column value for all the radiobuttons? You need to calculate the row and column based on the index.

Comment: Well partly because of a misunderstanding of what it does. But my initial plan was to use the range of the index in order to create all the buttons in a cleaner way. so I thought I could use columnspan/rowspan in order to tell it to span across selected columns/rows. But clearly didn't not work how i thought it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put those radiobuttons using `.grid()` and calculate the row and column based on the index:

```py
for index in range(len(characters)):
    Radiobutton(frame2,
        compound = TOP,
        image = characterList[index],
        text = characters[index],
        variable = v,
        value = index,
    ).grid(
        row = index//10,
        column = index%10,
    )
```

The above code will put ten radiobuttons in a row.  You can change 10 to other value to suit your requirement.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thank you so much for the help.